# Internals of retrieving database result

Tags: database, resultset

I'm trying to learn more about database internals, but there is one thing I don't understand for which I've found no resources.

When database has found requested rows, are they all sent to the client, or user has to retrieve rows one by one?
If second is true, shouldn't that generate many round time trips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each query fired all the result rows are sent at once.

Comment: Does engine concatenate all rows in one big string which is sent to client or is there some other mechanism?

Comment: MS SQL server uses Tabular Data Stream for transporting the data. Search for Tabular Data Stream in google and you will get to know more about it.